# Get width of a label in Titanium mobile app

Tags: iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile

How can I get the width of a label after set its contents? No initial width set to it.

I have two labels within a table row like followings:

```
label 1 (label 2)
```

Here the width of `label 1` is not set initially. with the change of contents `label 1`'s width has changes and sometimes it causes overlapping with `label 2`.

Now my main aim is to set the `label 2` left dynamically that it does not ovelapp with `label 1`. I want to do it like following:

1. first calculate the width of `label 1`
2. then set the left of `label 2 = width of label 1 + 10`

if there is any other way please help.

***HERE SOME CODE***

```
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    title: 'Cleos',
    backgroundImage: 'tablebg.png',
    navBarHidden: true,
});
var tableview = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    separatorStyle: Ti.UI.iPhone.TableViewSeparatorStyle.NONE,
    style: Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewStyle.PLAIN
});
win.add(tableview);
var modelData = new Array;
for (i = 0; i <= daga.length - 1; i++) { // `data` as json, comes from a source
    var row = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
        height: 120.0,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        selectedBackgroundColor: '#380710',
        hasDetail: true
    });
    var imageThumb = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
        image: '...',
        width: 100.0,
        height: 100.0,
        left: 4.0,
        top: 10.0
    });
    row.add(imageThumb);
    var name = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
        text: '...',
        font: {
            fontSize: 16,
            fontWeight: 'bold'
        },
        textAlign: 'left',
        color: '#fff',
        height: 30.0,
        top: 5.0,
        left: 110.0
    });
    row.add(modelname);
    var NumberOfImages = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
        text: '(' + 12 + ')',
        font: {
            fontSize: 16
        },
        width: 'auto',
        color: '#bfbebe',
        textAlign: 'left',
        height: 30.0,
        top: 5.0,
        left: '' // I want to set this `left  = width of label name`
    });
    row.add(NumberOfImages);
    modelData.push(row);
    tableview.setData(modelData);
}
win.open();
```

Comment: try to set NumberOfImages label textAlight to right and then check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var labelWidth = label.width;
```

but be careful with 'auto' values since they often return 0. the value should be requested *after* adding the label to the view.

**[update]**
if `NumberOfImages.left = name.width+name.left;` doesn't work i would try to calculate the width like

```
var pixelPerChar = 8;
var pseudoWidth = name.text.length/pixelPerChar;
NumberOfImages.left = pseudoWidth + name.left;
```

Comment: if initial width is `auto` and then after window load i want to get the width in that case `label.width` doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

```
var width = label.toImage().width;
```

This will get the real width or height (in pixels) of the image AND it takes into account the font properties (size, family, weight).

Comment: It's worth noting that the value you get back is in pixels, and not "platform specific units" which is the case for your standard View width property.

Answer (score 1):

Set both width AND height to auto, then it should return a proper value.

Comment: if initial width is `auto` and then after window load i want to get the width in that case `label.width` doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, but could you post some code how you created your label, or window.. The object you need the width from?

Comment: you add `modelName` to your row, and the label you made is `name`. And beside that, try setting width:'auto' explicitly in your code, don't leave it out. Once you added width:'auto' in the creation of the name label you can call name.width I think.

Answer (score 1):

Titanium labels with `auto` sizes tend to be annoying (or were when I last worked with Titanium); a solution that often works is to place them inside of a `TiView` with `auto` width or height and then read the relevant property from the view.

Answer (score 1):

Set the width of `name` to 'auto' when you create it.

After you add `name` to row, you can get the width by `name.size.width`

Comment: Hi Jeff.. I did as you said row.add(placeAddressLabel); alert(placeAddressLabel.size); where width:'230dp',height:'auto' is defined...but give width and height 0 in android.. any guesses.... ?

Answer (score 0):

Setting width to 'auto' seems to clip to 320 (the label won't stay one line if its bigger than the screen width). Is there a way to have a label bigger than the screen with an automatic width go past the screen edg

Answer (score 0):

I have also this type of problem in Starting. 
You, solve this problem easily, u set the height with %age (percentage).
It means, when u define 
label.height = 10%
label.left = 5% etc
then, it calculate the screen current height and set by default with percentage.

In This use we have also a profit. when we change the orientation than it take place easily, with percentage.

Thanks

Comment: but how to manage when you have to add label inside table's row not to view ?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738397/titanium-label-over-lapping-issue