# Titanium : Label over lapping issue

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

**For Android**

I have two labels in a table row. I am trying to set these two label vertical but the `firstLabel` overlaps the second one. As `firstLabel`'s height is "**auto**" and it contains dynamic text e.g. 10 lines , 20 line.

Due to dynamic height of `firstLabel` I couldn't set `secondLabel`'s top so it gets overlapped.

I've tried all possible solution available on the SO and Appcelerator but couldn't find the fix.

1). I couldn't get height of `firstLabel` after or before adding it to the view, table's row etc...

2) Tried to [set height of label according to text's length](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/31191/retrieving-height-of-labels-after-setting-text-value) but couldn't fix it .

Still looking for the solution..

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you'll need to do is not to set the layout to vertical on the label, but rather on the view that is containing all the labels.  If the parent view has a vertical layout, it will place the second label immediately after the first label ends.  Additionally, setting the "top" property of the second label will place that many units between the bottom of label1 and top of label 2.  Think relative positioning of block elements in CSS.

Comment: To add to the issue you are having with getting the dynamic view, all devices have different resolutions and densities so the app doesn't know what the height will be until it is displayed on the screen.  So you can get the height value after adding the label to the window and opening the window.

Comment: You know man.. I was trying to solve it from last 2 days ! I didn't know anything about android's layout structure n all.... Really appreciate your help...Thanks a lot it works...

Comment: one more thing... what modification do I need to set an image view horizontal, means left side where blank space is available ?

Comment: I think with the image view the image is stretched to the size of the view, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Actually, if I put image view then my first label will be put after the image view.Say image view's height is 50 then first label will start from 52 automatically...

Comment: That's only the case if the row is vertically positioned.

Comment: What you want to do then is set the row to position horizontally. It will be the same concept. Keep in mind, you can put views inside views so you might want to set the row to horizontal and have the imageview as well as a normal view (which contains the labels) and set the normal view to vertical.

Comment: for quick solution.. I set my first label's top to '-50dp' so its positioned just beside to image view with '65dp' left padding...

Comment: ya true.. but I tried with view and added my labels into the view and set layout vertical to the view and row's layout to horizontal... but it couldn't work... see this http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/133951/titanium-how-to-set-vertical-and-horizontal-layout-of-tables-row

Comment: What I would do is this: 
1) create tableViewRow with position set to horizontal.
2) add imageView and view1 to tableviewRow.
3) set view1 position to vertical and left to 10
4) add labels to view1 with textAlign set to 'left'

What this will do is, it will create an image which will be flush against the left side of the tableViewRow. It will then take the dynamic width of the image and add a 10px left margin to the view1.  It will then add the left aligned labels to view1.

Comment: hi can u please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802302/titanium-android-view-not-attached-to-window-manager-chrash

Answer (score 0):

Solved... According to DannyM 's answer . I also notice that, adding order of label into the row also matters.

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
{
    // Create a row and set its height to auto
    row = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow
    ({
        height:'auto',
        layout :'vertical'
    });

    var currentObj = results[i];
    // Create the label to hold the place name
    var placeNameLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel
    ({
        text:currentObj.PlaceName,
        left:'75dp',
        top:'auto',
        width:'auto',
        height:'18dp',              
        textAlign:'left',
        font:{fontSize:'14dp',fontWeight:'bold'},
        wordWrap:true
    });

    var placeAddressLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel
    ({
        text:currentObj.PlaceAddress,
        left:'75dp',
        top:'auto',
        width:'230dp',
        height:'auto',      
        textAlign:'left',
        font:{fontSize:'14dp'}                  
    });

    var checkInDate = Titanium.UI.createLabel
    ({
        text:currentObj.CheckInDate+' '+currentObj.CheckInTime,
        left:'75dp',
        top:'auto', //placeAddressLabel.height + 30 +'dp',
        width:'165dp',
        height:'25dp',
        textAlign:'left',
        font:{fontSize:'14dp'},
        wordWrap:true,
    });

    row.add(placeNameLabel);
    row.add(placeAddressLabel);
    row.add(checkInDate)

    tableData[i] = row;
 }
 return tableData ;
```