# Titanium Android: View not attached to window manager chrash

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I have two views.In first view, I have a table view and I am displaying remote data in its cells. I am showing activity indicator while data downloading.

Second view gets open when any of row is selected.

When I come back to the first view, I am refreshing the table view by downloading remote data.

But in Android, when I come back to first view and start downloading data, application gets crash due to activity indicator !!! Application crashes only in Android, its working fine in iPhone !!

I am refreshing the table's data in **focus** event of current window.

the error : -

> Activity org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity has leaked window
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@450c4488 that
>   was originally added here E/WindowManager(  324):
>   android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity
>   org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity has leaked window
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@450c4488 that
>   was originally added here

and

> (main) [2225,140482] Sending event: exception on thread: main
>   msg:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window
>   manager; Titanium 1.8.1,2012/01/27 17:31,a24502a E/TiApplication( 
>   324): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window
>   manager

**EDITED**

my code : -

```
var currentWindow = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;

var placeTableData = [] ;
var placeTableView = Titanium.UI.createTableView
({
    data:placeTableData,
    top:'0dp',
    height:'365dp'
});

currentWindow.addEventListener('focus',winopened);
function winopened(e)
{
    placeTableData = createRow();
}

function createRow() 
{   
    currentWindow.add(activity);
    activity.show();    
    currentWindow.touchEnabled = false;

    // downloading data 

    if(loader1.DONE)
    {
        currentWindow.touchEnabled = true ;
        activity.hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is activity indicator added to the first window, in which you have first view?

Comment: how can you add ai to table view? It should be the part of window

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan: can you please come at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9135/titanium

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan: now i am adding ai to the currentWindow...but still same issue.Also now I am creating cells in the same file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved !!! I found that, in Android, when you press back button, it doesn't handle proper navigation to the previous view. It simply displays previous view without take care of current view.

So it necessary to close current view properly before displaying another view. So I closed current view before displaying the previous view.

When we press back button on Android, `android:back` event of `Window` get call. So I closed current window in this method , like :

```
Titanium.UI.currentWindow.addEventListener('android:back',function(e)
{
    Ti.API.info('back button pressed');
    currentWindow.close();
});
```